# Jquery - Load Extermal Page In The DIV

Tags: jquery

I need help on this loading a external URL into a DIV.  It is not just $("#DIV-ID").load(URL), but a little bit more to that, so let me explain what I want to accomplish.

Says, I have a main.html page looks like this (I skipped the jquery include and misc stuff so it won't confuse everyone)

```
<!-- main.html -->
<script>
$(function(){ // document ready

    loadPage1 = function()
    {
        //alert("submit");
        var url = "page1.html"
        $("#content").load(url); 

    }
});
</script>

<div id="left">
    <a href="javascript:loadPage1()">Load Page 1</a>
</div>
```

The code above (main.html) works fine. When I click the "Load Page 1" link, it will load the external page1.html (below) into the DIV "content".

```
<!-- page1.html -->
<script>
$(function(){ // document ready
    $("#content").load("leftMenu.asp"); 

    loadPage2 = function()
    {
        //alert("submit");
        var url = "page2.html"
        $("#content").load(url); 

    }
});
</script>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:loadPage2()">Load Page 2</a>
</div>
```

Now, I am still viewing the main.html with a new content loaded from the page1.html which has a link "Load Page 2".  The problem is when I click on the link "Load Page 2", it opens in the parent page and no longer stay in the main.html page.

What I would like to do is that when I click "Load Page 2" from page1.html, it just reload the page2.html in the same DIV "content" without refreshing entire page or opens in the parent window.

Please help.  Thanks!

Comment: none of the functions shown should work since they aren't in global namespace that is needed by the href code. Look at errors thrown in console. Are you sure you copied code correctly to question?

Comment: Since my pages have so many stuff in it.  I shortened the version so I can explain it easier.  Assume the page has jquery file included, global namespace... and it works fine until the last link "Load Page 2" opens the page as parent window, not within the DIV "content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your function one time (in main.html) and making it flexible enough to take the `href` parameter from the links in dynamically loaded pages. This means you will have to put the actual URL of the page you want to load in the `href` instead of your function reference, then just make a new function for your anchor tags. I will show this using the `.get()` method instead of the `.load()` method:

HTML for main.html:

```
<!-- main.html -->
<div id="content"><h1>This is the main page content</h1></div>
<div id="left">
    <a href="page1.html">Load Page 1</a>
</div>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    loadPage = function(URL)
    {
    var content = $.get(URL, function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    });

    }
    //function to detect your link clicks (links should probably have some kind of class or ID, but I am keeping this simple to illustrate
    $('a').click(function(){
        var URL = $(this).attr('href');
        loadPage(URL);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Then, page1.html will not need any script, just the link to load the next page you want:

```
<!-- page1.html -->
<h1>This is Page 1 content!</h1>
<div>
    <a href="page2.html">Load Page 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I just tested your method and it opened the page1.html, but it opens in the parent window.   What I would like to do is load the page1.html in the DIV "content" and still preserve the other DIV ID="left" and everything else on the main.html page.  I use the DIV ID="left" as a navigation menu.

Comment: I just double-checked my code and tested locally -- I forgot `return false;` on the anchor button function (like a dummy) and if you didn't catch that, your page would just be redirecting like a normal link. After fixing, I could get page contents to load into just the `#content` div and keep the `#left` div there. Thus, you could put all your links in that persistent `#left` div. Code is updated above to catch the mistake.

Comment: It only works on the first link "Load Page 1". After it loaded page1.html in the "content", then click "Load Page 2", it will redirecting as normal link.  I want to load page2.html in the same "content" and still have the left DIV with "Load Page 1" link there.  Is that possible?

Comment: Not knowing the exact context of what you're doing, I suggest either: 1) Put all links for swapping out content into that left DIV, or 2) A script like the following would delegate that ajax function to links in `#content` (though you should probably make those links have a unique class or something):
`$('#content').on('click', 'a', function(){
        var URL = $(this).attr('href');
        loadPage(URL);
        return false;
});`

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your loadpage object, the **var content =**  I think but want to be sure that you could have named that anything; it's not related to #content I presume.
Thanks.